# Looking for the immediate response which helps me a lot

Tags: json, angular

How to store form template to database by using Angular through Json files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store things from Angular app to database directly, it's only client-side application.

So if you want to interact with a database from your app you need to create an API. NodeJS is good for this, [here an example](https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express/). But you can do it with Java API, or whatever you want while it's an API.

Once you got your API you can send data from your Angular app to your API and then from your API to your database. The data can be Json, Objects, String, ...

Comment: Hi Alexis . Thanks for the explanation and it helps us the way to know better . Along with the same , we are trying to save the complete template to the database by not separating the fields of data inside the template . Hope you understand my concern. 

Please do help in how can we save a template to a particular database instead of data !!! 

Awaiting for your response

Comment: If I understand well you are trying to save the entire html ? If so you can get it with `document.documentElement.innerHTML`, this will give you your html template as a string, after you could store it like so (a string) in your database easily. Is it your issue ?